# How to avoid restarting the service?

Tags: android, service, restart

I created a service and want this service was always running.
But when I close the application which created the service, Android removes the service, and then it restarts.

The service in my application is created by pressing the button in the `MainActivity` as follows:

```
startService(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MyService.class));
```

**Logcat:**

> 01-22 11:44:52.242    1218-1389/system_process I/ActivityManager﹕
>   Killing 2040:com.my.application/u0a10046: remove task 01-22
>   11:44:52.252    1218-1218/system_process W/ActivityManager﹕ Scheduling
>   restart of crashed service com.my.application/.MyService in 5000ms
>   01-22 11:44:57.272    2061-2061/? D/dalvikvm﹕ Not late-enabling
>   CheckJNI (already on) 01-22 11:44:57.272    1218-1235/system_process
>   I/ActivityManager﹕ Start proc com.my.application for service
>   com.my.application/.MyService : pid=2061 uid=10046 gids={50046, 1028}

Answer (score 1):

In your Service class, adding "return START_NOT_STICKY" as follow:

```
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    // your code ...
    return START_NOT_STICKY;
}
```

the meaning of START_NOT_STICKY is that (mentioned on the java doc of Service.java):

> Constant to return from onStartCommand(Intent, int, int): if this service's
>   process is killed while it is started (after returning from
>   onStartCommand(Intent, int, int)), and there are no new start intents to deliver to it, then take the service out of the started state and don't recreate
>   until a future explicit call to startService()
>   .  The service will not receive a onStartCommand(Intent, int, int) call with a null Intent because it will not be re-started if there are no pending Intents to deliver.

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply.
But I meant how to prevent   stopping the service after the app was killed?

Comment: Sorry for misunderstanding your question. If letting users know your service is allowed, I think you could use startForeground() in your Service class,just like some music player

Comment: I already thought about it.
But in this case, the posted Notification window.
And I don't need it.

Answer (score 1):

The behavour has changed several times with different Android versions. You can't prevent Android from killing your `Service` in some cases. On some Android versions, it can help if you put your `Service` in a separate process. Usually, when you swipe the app from the list of recent tasks, Android will then kill the process hosting your activities, but leave the process hosting your `Service`. To do that, add

```
android:process=":service"
```

to the `<service>` declaration in the manifest.

Be aware that you will now have 2 processes running, and that makes some things more complicated. If you have a custom `Application` class, an instance of it will be created in EACH process. If you rely on `static` variables, they are not shared across processes. This can make your life miserable if you don't understand what is going on.